# How to convert keyboard controls to touch screen in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, 2d, pong

Complete newbie here. Using Unity C#. I'm looking at moving my PONG game from keyboard control to touch screen. Here is my working keyboard code:

// Player 1 => Controls left bat with W/S keys

public GameObject leftBat;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

```
//Defualt speed of the bat to zero on every frame
leftBat.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);

//If the player is pressing the W key...
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {

    //Set the velocity to go up 1
    leftBat.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0f, 8f, 0f);
}

//If the player is pressing the S key...
else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {

    //Set the velocity to go down 1 (up -1)
    leftBat.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0f, -8f, 0f);


}
```

}

I found this code and been playing around with it but to now avail.

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player_Input_Controller : MonoBehaviour {

```
public GameObject leftBat;
public float paddleSpeed = 1f;
public float yU;
public float yD;

private Ray ray;
private RaycastHit rayCastHit;

private Vector3 playerPos = new Vector3(0, -9.5f, 0);

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0))
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out rayCastHit)){
            Vector3 position = rayCastHit.point;

            float yPos = position.y;
            playerPos = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(yPos, yU, yD), -9.5f, 0f);
            transform.position = playerPos; 
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any one have a touchscreen Pong script I could use, or know how to edit this one?

Again, I'm really new and I'm sorry if I look like the Dummy in the class.

Thanks for any help provided. I REALLY appreciate it. This is the last hurdle in completing my game.

Comment: Hey, do you want to control the bats using onscreen invisible buttons (simplest solution)? in that case you won't need to raycast anything

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you do not need any raycasting. Because you are working in 2D and you are only concerned about the y value of `Input.mousePosition`. Therefore, you can calculate the extent of your screen using your camera's z value. If your camera is at `(0, 0, -10)` lets say your extents in the game will be `-5 - BatOffset` to `5+BatOffset` in your world coordinates. Therefore, you somehow need a function to map `Screen.height` to your world coordinate extents as you can see from the image.

[image]

In conclusion you need to find  `Input.mousePosition.y` divide it to `Screen.height`. This will give you the ratio where you touch or click. Then find the position in world space.

**Note that:** you can also use `Input.touchPosition.y`. Following script will work for you to do this operation:

```
public GameObject cam;
private Vector3 batPos;
private float minY;
private float maxY;
private int Res;
private float deltaY;

void Start () {
    minY = cam.transform.position.z / 2 - gameObject.transform.localScale.y;
    maxY = (-cam.transform.position.z / 2) + gameObject.transform.localScale.y;
    deltaY = maxY - minY;
    Debug.Log(minY + " " + maxY + " " + deltaY);
    Res = Screen.height;

    batPos = gameObject.transform.position;

}

void Update () {
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // we find the height we have to go up from minY
        batPos.y =minY + Input.mousePosition.y / Res * deltaY;
        gameObject.transform.position = batPos;
    }       
}
```

This works for me in the editor when you click on screen with mouse. You just have to change the parts `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` to `Touch` commands such as `Touch.tapCount > 0`. Also this script should be attached to the bat. Good luck!

**Also** You can use Orthographic camera and Orthographic camera size instead of `cam.transformation.z`

Comment: AH! perfect man. Responds just fine to touch. It stays within the bounds and everything.  Is it possible to make the bat respond to a drag function opposed to jumping to the clicked point/touched point.

Comment: Yes you can use [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html). It will move the bat to the clicked position smoothly.

Comment: Also i now realized you can remove `if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` section and it will be dragging the bat.

Comment: remove the if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) and Replace it with the Vector3.Lerp, or just remove the if statement?

Comment: No replacement just remove the if part you do not need lerp

Comment: So in a ration of 16:9 on a mobile phone the resolution is 1024x576. height then equals 576.    The orthographic size of the camera is 5.3. So bat inputs will be -2.65 -BatOffset and 2.65+BatOffset. It can't go past the upper and lower bounds which are (0:1;0) which translate to  64 pixels. so the playable area is 512 pixels. SO, the code should look something like this:

Comment: Is there a line I can put in to keep the bat between the rigid body boundaries or does that have to be defined by the camera as well?

Comment: Well you can define a boundary with maxY and minY. Lets say if calculated position is bigger than minY assign position to minY. Therefore, your bat can never go beyond the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

**May be helpfull**

1. create script. for example player.cs

   ```
   public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
         bool  swipeRight = false;
         bool  swipeLeft = false;
         bool touchBlock = true;
         bool canTouchRight = true;
         bool canTouchLeft = true;

        void Update()
        {
              swipeLeft = Input.GetKeyDown("a") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow);
              swipeRight = Input.GetKeyDown("d") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow);
              TouchControl();    
             if(swipeRight)  //rightMove logic
             else if(swipeLeft) //leftMove logic
       }

      void TouchControl()
      {
            if(Input.touchCount  == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began )
           {
                //Jump logic 
            }
           else  if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && touchBlock == true) 
          {
                 touchBlock = false;
                // Get movement of the finger since last frame
                var touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
                Debug.Log("touchDeltaPosition "+touchDeltaPosition);

                if(touchDeltaPosition.x > 0 && canTouchRight == true)
               {
                    //rightMove
                    swipeRight = true; canTouchRight = false;
                     Invoke("DisableSwipeRight",0.2f);
                 }
                 else  if(touchDeltaPosition.x < 0 && canTouchLeft == true)
                {
                     //leftMove
                     swipeLeft = true; canTouchLeft = false;
                     Invoke("DisableSwipeLeft",0.2f);
                  }       
            } 
    }
   void DisableSwipeLeft()
    {
        swipeLeft = false;
        touchBlock = true;
        canTouchLeft = true;
    }
    void DisableSwipeRight()
    {
        swipeRight = false;
        touchBlock = true;
        canTouchRight = true;
    }
    }
   ```